# How to migrate code using Apache Jena HttpAuthenticator to Jena 4.3.2?

Tags: java, jena

I want to migrate code using Apache Jena 2.13.0 to 4.3.2.
Using Maven, I changed the dependency to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Following https://jena.apache.org/documentation/migrate_jena2_jena3.html, I also replaced all occurrences of `import com.hp.hpl.jena` with `import org.apache.jena.`. While this got rid of the majority of compiler errors, the following classes are not available:

```java
org.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.HttpAuthenticator
org.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.SimpleAuthenticator
```

How should I deal with those two classes? Are they under a different path now or are they gone altogether? Or do I need another dependency?

The classes are only used in this code block:

```
HttpAuthenticator auth = null;
if (conf.getAuthPassword() != null && !conf.getAuthPassword().equals("")) {
    auth = new SimpleAuthenticator(conf.getAuthUsername(),
                conf.getAuthPassword().toCharArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Jena 4.3.x has switched to using the JDK provided java.net.http for HTTP requests.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/sparql-apis/http-auth.html

Those two classes were part of the support for the previous use of a different HttpClient library.

The `<dependency>` shown have is enough.